# Dynamically creating views

Tags: android

I want to create a function that takes in an array of text and creates buttons and adds them to the view.
This is my code. 
It is working and creating the buttons but when i call the function twice it doesn't create two linear layouts it just shows the last one called as if it is deleting the first one.
How can i make it to create a new linear layout and add it to the View?

```
// Create a view 
protected boolean CreateTheButtons(String[] names)
{
    try
    {
             LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
             linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
             LayoutParams linLayoutParam = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
             // set LinearLayout as a root element of the screen 
             linLayout.setWeightSum(names.length);
             setContentView(linLayout, linLayoutParam);

             LayoutParams lpView = new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
             lpView.weight = 1;

             for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {

             Button btn = new Button(this);
             btn.setText(names[i]);
             linLayout.addView(btn, lpView);

             }
             return true;
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {

         return false;
     }




}
```

Comment: why did i get a -1 on the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is working and creating the buttons but when i call the function
>   twice it doesn't create two linear layouts it just shows the last one
>   called as if it is deleting the first one.

Your code removes the first `LinearLayout` resulted from calling the method because you use `setContentView()`(which will replace the current view of the activity(if any is found) with the view that you pass as a parameter). Instead you should remove the call to `setContentView()` and insert a holder ViewGroup for the `LinearLayouts` that you plan to add through that method.

```
<!-- This will be the content view of the activity -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/parent" />
```

Set the layout above as the content view for the activity, in the `onCreate()` method:

```
setContentView(R.layout.the_layout_above);
```

In the method you'll then have:

```
protected boolean CreateTheButtons(String[] names) {
    try {
             LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
             linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams linLayoutParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);              
             linLayout.setWeightSum(names.length);
             // assuming this method is in an Activity
             LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
             parent.addView(linLayout, linLayoutParam);

             LayoutParams lpView = new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
             lpView.weight = 1;

             for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {

             Button btn = new Button(this);
             btn.setText(names[i]);
             linLayout.addView(btn, lpView);
             }
             return true;
     } catch(Exception ex) {
         return false;
     }

}
```

Comment: I have another question ... what i am actually trying to do is create a library that creates the buttons in a linear view ... I tried researching how to create a library but the results didnt help me.

How can i do this to be called as a function. Can it be an Activity or it has to be a Fragment?

If you need me to open another question i will.

Comment: @DanyMinassian I don't see where do you have problems? Creating the library project or with the actual code for the addition. For something this simple a library is probably too much.

Comment: yes i know it is too much but its a university project so i have to :P. I got it to work. Thank you for your time